# KeyError: label not in index WHEN IT CLEARLY IS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a somewhat complex lookup of dates in multiple tables. I've run into this error a bunch and have previously found what was wrong and fixed it.

Here, I'm puzzled.  I like to oversimplify the issue so I can figure it out.  The following has me scratching my head:

```
print ('04/01/2009' in trouble_df['Date'])
>False
```

OK, so the index isn't in the list I'm looking at.  So I pulled up this list, and found the value '04/01/2009', along with its index.  So I tried:

```
print (trouble_df['Date'][157])
>04/01/2009
```

Maybe the date is the wrong datatype.

```
print (type(trouble_df['Date'][157]))
> <class 'str'>
```

Nope.  OK, how is this possible:

```
print (trouble_df['Date'][157] in trouble_df['Date'])
>False
```

Please help!

Comment: Try also printing its `len`. There might be *SPACE*s (or other "hidden" chars) at the end. Regarding the last part, I have 0 *Pandas* knowledge, but if a dataframe works like a `dict` then the last `print` is fine, you might have wanted to type `if 157 in trouble_df['Date'])`.

Comment: Also, is this python 3 or 2? `str` in python 3 is Unicode, which opens up a host of potential causes

Comment: If you want to search through the Series, you should use `trouble_df['Date'][157] in trouble_df['Date'].values`. Otherwise it searches the index.

Answer (score 0):

`in` is work for list in pandas it is `isin`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':['01/01/2018','01/02/2018']})
df.id.isin(['01/01/2018']).any()
Out[659]: True
'01/01/2018' in df.id.tolist()
Out[660]: True
```